Proper Pisot n-tuples
Recall that x is a Pisot number if it is real and x>1, while all of its conjugates have magnitude less than 1.  Then  $\{(x)^k\}$ (where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part of x) approaches 0 rapidly as $k\rightarrow \infty$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number)
Define x,y to be a Pisot pair  if $\{(x)^k+(y)^k\}$,  approaches 0 as $k\rightarrow \infty$ and say that this pair is Proper if neither $\{(x)^k\}$ or $\{(y)^k\}$ approach 0 as $k\rightarrow \infty$.
Then the existence of Proper Pisot Pairs follows from essentially the same analysis, where $x,y$ are real and greater than one and all other conjugates with them have magnitude less than 1.
An example arises from the polynomial $x^3 - 10x^2 + 20x + 1 = 0$ where
$x \approx 2.844$ and $y\approx 7.205$ while the 3rd root is  $x \approx -0.049$.
This could also be extended the Pisot n-tuples.
What is known about these variants?
